# How to get all unique IDs from the list of dicts?

Tags: python

Say you have a list of dicts like this `{'id': 1, 'other_value':5}`

So maybe;

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'other_value':5}, {'id': 1, 'other_value2':6}, {'id': 2, 'other_value':4}, {'id': 2, 'other_value2':3}]
```

Now, you can assume this is a small subset of the data. There are maybe thousands. Also the structure isn't specified by me, its given to me.

If I just want to get the IDs out I could do something like this:

```
ids = [i[id] for i in items]
```

However, you'll notice there are duplicate id's in the original data. so the question is; how can you tidily get the unique ID's?

I was hoping for something like:

```
ids = [i[id] for i in items if not in LIST]
```

but as far as i know there isn't a way to access the list in the generator.

of course I can do a for loop and easily do it that way. I was just curious to know if there was a more concise way of doing this.

Comment: d0ougal, it's a beginner level question, no one says that you are. please don't remove the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want unique id's you can use a set:

```
set(i['id'] for i in items)
```

Comment: you don't have to create the intermediate list yourself. `set(i['id'] for i in items)` will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
set(i['id'] for i in items)
```

but you might consider another data structure altogether, for example dict of lists:

```
items = {1: [5, 6], 2: [2, 4]}
```